# Mark an Outlook message as read with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, rule

Is there a way to mark a message as read if that message has been replied to?

Example: *this is my E-Mail*
**RE: this is my E-Mail**

Can I mark both as read?

Answer (score 36):

An outlook `MailItem` has a property `.UnRead`:

> Returns or sets a Boolean value that is True if the Outlook item has not been opened (read). Read/write.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.unread.aspx

Assuming you have a handle on these mailItems, simply set their respective `.UnRead = False` to mark them as read.

Comment: the issue with that is, I may have had the item unread, however someone on my team may have replied to it meaning I don't need to look at that E-Mail. I am thinking some kind of match with the RE: added in the title.

Comment: I don't understand how that is an issue. Assuming you already know the email has been replied to, then this answer should work. If you do not know whether the email has yet been replied to, then that is a separate question (which you did **not** ask in your original Q).

Comment: I get 800 E-Mails a day my team and I try to work them as we can we open the unread/un-replied E-Mails… it would just make it better to know that it had already been worked.

Comment: **WHAT IS YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION?** Don't bury it in the comments here, either revise *this* original question, or ask a new one. You're a busy person at work, I'm sure. Assume that anyone who might be willing to help you here is *also* busy, and doesn't want to spend hours dickering about trying to figure out what your *actual problem* is.  Give us the common courtesy of describing your problem in detail.